# Remove specific formatting from style in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I would like to remove a format specification from a style so that it is inherited from the linked style.

Let's assume I have set a font (e.g. Courier 12) and would like to clear that particular setting so that the font is inherited from the linked style. How do I achieve that?

To be clear, I do not want to delete the entire style, or change the style element (e.g. font) to another value, I would like to remove this specification altogether from the style while keeping the style.

Comment: Try this : Change the font to the one used by Normal.

Comment: For some attributes you may be able to remove them in the UI, for instance if they have a three-state toggle.  If the UI won't let you remove them, there's a way of editing the `.docx` file directly, which I explain in [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/1449672/187651).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Styles Task Pane (`Alt + Ctrl + Shift + S`) and locate the Style Name in the pane. Right click the style name and choose Modify.

In the Style Formatting dialog, change the `Style based on` setting to the style name you want this particular style to clone. Then in the `Formatting` font name control change the setting to the font name used in the style you are cloning. This will effectively erase the custom font setting that is applied to the style.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Howver, I find this very strange: fixing e.g. a font size should be something different from inheriting it from the underlying style. In a way it should be possible to fix the two to the same value and then change the underlying value without having the derived style change.