# After I click on a Linked Styles, why does Word fail to apply it to text?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

Pls see the GIF below. This snag happens randomly, and happens to entire paragraphs and text in paragraph (when I'm trying to color only some words in a paragraph).

With my cursor I highlighted Purple 1 then clicked on Normal twice, but nothing changes!

Yet when with my cursor I highlighted Purple 4 then click on Normal twice, Purple 4 changed to Normal Style! Why?

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, it's difficult to deal with random problems. It's recommended to rename **Normal** template for a test. _Go to C:\Users\<user name >\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates, then find the Normal.dotm and rename it_ . This file will be automatically generated when reopen Word.

Comment: Your first image is too small to read. Please post somewhere a small document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @harrymc Do you see the GIF? Please download the Word doc: https://mega.nz/file/SkQlXYaC#6RRXOEEK3WvKqkK5QxWLxX0wByVjuXebFed2Zs6qelE.

Comment: I added an answer to explain what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what a style does, right-click it and select *Modify*.
This will give the details of the style.

**The Normal style:**

[image]

**The Purple style:**

[image]

It can be seen that Normal is a pure paragraph style, while Purple is linked,
meaning that it has both a paragraph style and a character style.

**For more details:**

Word styles have a very long history and are basically just patch upon patch,
creating an enormous complexity. Most of us just keep on patching our documents
until they look correct. There have been times when I copied text from Word to
notepad, just to get rid of unwanted effects.

There is a big difference between applying a style to part-of or to the entire
paragraph, called paragraph styles and character styles.
There is also a difference between direct and indirect styling, when style
is inherited from the paragraph or applied directly.
When you apply a style to part of a paragraph, you create a linked style,
meaning that it is linked-to and based-on some other basic style.

In your case,
when you apply the Normal style, then because it is pure paragraph,
it replaces the paragraph part of the Purple style for the text.
However, as it does not contain any character style, that part is left
as it is, and in this case this means that it keeps its font and color.

You were misled by Word displaying the Normal style as black-on-white
in the ribbon.
However, those just happen to be the default colors for text,
as the Normal style does not affect colors.

A useful way of making text A look exactly like text B, is to right-click
anywhere in B and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
to copy the total style of B. Then select the text in A and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
to paste the style.
Note that for setting only paragraph style, such as text alignment,
into exactly one paragraph, you do not have to select all of the paragraph,
just click anywhere in it and paste, and the paragraph style will
automatically apply to the entire paragraph.

Useful references if you wish to dig more into Word styles:

- [Why does Word sometimes override bold and italics when I apply a paragraph style, but sometimes it does not?](https://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/stylesoverridedirectformatting.html)
- [Linked Styles - Working with them in Microsoft Word](https://www.greatcirclelearning.com/new-blog/2017/12/14/linked-styles-working-with-them-in-microsoft-word).
- [Word 2010: Create a Style without a font color](https://superuser.com/questions/360488/word-2010-create-a-style-without-a-font-color).

Comment: Thanks again Harry! Out of curiosity, if you don't mind my asking, any plans for your 314K of reputation?

Comment: Unfortunately, reputation has no market value.

Answer (score 0):

I would have just commented, but don't have enough rep yet.

Your question intrigued me, as it's not something I have ever encountered. I came across this forum post: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2010-styles-dont-change/814e03ba-dc6c-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5. The answer(s) from Stefan Blom seemed to apply to your situation.

To summarize his responses, it appears what might be happening is that Purple 1 may have a "character style" applied. These styles apply only to the font and are applied on top of the "paragraph style". Normal in your Style window is a "paragraph style", so applying it only affects the entire paragraph and ignores any individual character styling.

If you highlight Purple 1, and press Ctrl+SpaceBar, it should remove any character styling applied and take on whatever paragraph format is applied.